# Conducting Ethical Phishing Attack

Tags: email, phishing, social-engineering, websites

For research purposes, I'm conducting an ethical phishing attack in my institution. I have permission from the institution for the same. I've created the phishing site and the email content, and I'll be recording who and how many users visited the phishing site. I intend to send links to a phishing website in the email like [this](http://somesite.com).

Where do I host this site and how do I send this email?

I've seen some free hosting sites. Do email providers give low reputation to such free hosting sites?

Also, for sending the email, should I choose popular email service providers like gmail, hotmail or should I use disposable email? What will increase the chances of the email reaching the users?

Comment: This really isn't a security question. This is purely up to your resources and what you want to accomplish. Why not send it from an email account within your institution? Why not host the site from within, too?

Comment: @Schroeder I doubt that this would be an authentic test. When I get a mail from `someone@myinsitution.example` saying to log into `http://myinsitution.example/application` using my username and password for `https://myinstitution.example/otherapplication`, then I would see no reason to doubt that.

Comment: @Philipp except if it comes from the wrong account and goes to an illegitimate site. Account takeovers can result in legit email accounts being used to stage this type of phishing. As I say, it all depends on what you want to accomplish. It also matters if this is internal emails.

Comment: @Schroeder I wasn't so much talking about the email address (I know these can be spoofed) but rather about the target URL of the phishing site. When it's hosted by my own institution, then I wouldn't assume it's phishing.

Comment: @Philipp see Hector's comments on DNS below .... hosting != legit domains

Comment: @Philipp heck, I've run internal phishing sites just using IPs and found no statistical difference between that and spoofed or typo-squatted domains, but the OP is looking for a place to host

Comment: @schroeder - I found with normal users it made no difference but with technical users they would notice the IP and be more hesitant. Although we also found technical users more likely to click a link knowing it was phishing due to curiosity / assuming clicking the link alone wasn't a risk until a further action was performed. I've also seen at another company that used phish.me developers noticed they used a header with their name in and set up filters to automatically report them...

Answer (score 3):

This question is, in part, *“How do I get my phishing emails past spam detection?”*  Any tricks we share could also be used by actual attackers, and [deliverability](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=email+deliverability) isn't the best use of your time.  Instead, *temporarily* configure your sending infrastructure to bypass threat detection so your test is not run through any spam filters.

**The easiest solution is to use a well-known testing agency** like [Cofense PhishMe](https://cofense.com/product-services/phishme/), [Proofpoint Anti-Phishing Training](https://www.proofpoint.com/us/learn-more/anti-phishing-suite), or [KnowBe4](https://www.knowbe4.com/products/kevin-mitnick-security-awareness-training/), and they'll do the heavy lifting and walk you through the rest.  This may not be ideal if you have a really small budget and/or if this is part of a student project.

#### A good in-house phishing test must

Have permission:

- Approval from an executive or director, not just IT or Engineering
- Relevant infosec and netops teams should sign off on this test

Use external servers:

- Send the test from an external IP address range
- Allowlist: Temporarily bypass anti-spam scanning for the test's sending IP(s)
  (Don't leave this around, that's a back door for future attacks to bypass detection!)

Identify itself as a phishing test in its headers:

- Add an `X-PHISHTEST` header with your contact info for escalations
- Leaving this indicator allows security groups to safely ignore reports

  > [image: ⚠] The `X-PHISHTEST` header triggers a “phishing attack” verdict in some spam detection solutions and **prevents the “[free pass](https://www.reddit.com/r/AskNetsec/comments/e642if/knowbe4_phish_tests/fa2kgxn/?context=3)” for reported phishing reports from meddling with real attack detection.**  Note the need for allowlisting above.

Have a good landing site:

- Consider a vanity domain like `<institution>-support.com`
- Embed each user address in the link's query string
- Log users' clicks and the IPs they clicked from for your report
- Tell users that they fell for your trap and educate them
- Link or host content similar to the [APWG](https://apwg.org/)'s [Stop.Think.Connect.](https://www.stopthinkconnect.org/tips-advice/general-tips-and-advice)
- Reveal the test at the document root or without a query string
  so security researchers can understand your intent

#### Bad phishing tests

- Will get into trouble with testers' management
- Can get larger accounts suspended
- Might get caught as spam and therefore fail to reach the targets
- Risk annoying yet not educating the user base
- Will confuse anti-spam filters when trained as phishing

#### Answers to your specific questions

***Where do I host this site and how do I send this email?***

So long as you follow the above rules about a good test and a good landing site, you shouldn't run into problems. As noted above, it is a good idea to alert your network operators (this includes your web hosting company) before you conduct this test.

***I've seen some free hosting sites. Do email providers give low reputation to such free hosting sites?***

You're probably referring to spam detection systems, which are nowadays extraordinarily complex, pulling in as much metadata as possible and combining it all with lots of secret sauce and machine learning. You really want to bypass spam detection with allowlisting. Client-side anti-spam is rarely powerful enough to discriminate in the manner you're worrying about.

***Also, for sending the email, should I choose popular email service providers like gmail, hotmail or should I use disposable email? What will increase the chances of the email reaching the users?***

Again, you need to bypass anti-spam, at which point much of this doesn't matter. A cheap vanity domain like `<institution>-support.com` likely comes with the ability to send within your provider's hosted environment.

I consider GMail and Hotmail to be disposable. Many penetration tests register accounts like `<institution>-support@gmail.com` and use good From display names like `<institution> Support` (which is the only thing mobile email clients display).

Answer (score 2):

First of all there are several services which provide phishing testing - PhishMe for example. Your post suggests a low level of technical ability which implies you should maybe consider using one of these instead of rolling your own.

Link-wise I'd again try and use a realistic-looking domain. If you have internal DNS then you can point users at this without actually having to pay to register the name. If you inject an ID into the link you can map who clicked it back to the end user (`nonexistanteventscompany.com/event/ab3fd4?invitee=[user@company.com]`).

Hosting-wise this could run internally on pretty much any machine that you can DNS the address to - just a basic web server that records the ID from the link in a database (could probably just be a Python script).

Comment: and I challenge your advice about getting a 'realistic' domain - the stats are that it just doesn't matter - I own `phishys.com` and use it as a control in my phishing research, and it gets as many hits as 'realistic looking' domains - internal phishing is successful even if you only use IPs in the link

Comment: Updated the answer. With relation to domains i'd argue phishys doesn't look suspicious enough - a domain that short/readable is too expensive for mass-phishers to touch since they get burnt so quickly. Its also not intuitive to read "phish" from it. I've certainly seen differences - although tend to be in environments with a majority of tech literate users.